# How do I know if my cat's microchip meets the ISO 11784/11785 standard?

Tags: cats

I can't reach the vet that microchipped my cat. All I know is the microchip number but I don't get any result with that number from any registry website.

Comment: Do you have accute worries, or is it simple for your curiosity?

Comment: I'm going to relocate with my cat and this is a requirement from the destination country.

Comment: As far as I know, the information at registration websites is that one, the owner provides

Comment: A short overlook about the ISO chips says, that EU compatible chips (that one require ISO) seem to have 10 digits, whereas US chips usually have 9 digits. No guarantee about this, source: https://www.petrelocation.com/blog/post/iso-compatible-microchips-for-pet-travel-to-the-european-union ... I am sorry, but I have today not more time to research.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My cat's chip number has 15 digits, guess it's not compatible then

Comment: seems 15 is fine also: http://www.maxmicrochip.com/ISO_types.htm

Comment: Here is a list to decode the first 3 numbers of the code, if it is 900 or bigger, then it is for the producer, so you can have a look if the producer works with ISO... http://www.maxmicrochip.com/ISO_types.htm

Comment: Thanks again! My cat's microchip number starts with 900225 and it seems it could belong to various manufacturers, I'll try my luck...

Comment: https://notpfote.de/informationen-rund-um-den-legalen-sauberen-tierschutz/laendercodes-der-chipnummern/ Sorry posted two times the same link... the second one should have been this

Comment: No worries, google showed me something similar :)

Comment: related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16402/microchips-which-national-database-hosts-the-record-if-the-pet-moved-between-co

Comment: @ec08b914 if this question is about the actual standard, it would be more suitable for law SE.